# POWER BI Measure for dividing total sales by each person by total sales

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have made an measure for showing total sales by each person. I can't figure how to make an measure for dividing total sales by each person BY total sales. For example, for the person "bmo" I want to calculate 303/3153 and so on.

[image: Photo]

I have tried using the same measure as I use on "Totalt antall salg" and use the Show value as, but that just shows the correct value, and does not calculate it, and I need to use the number for later.

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore filter context by using ALL to get total sales:

```
VAR _TotalSales = 
 CALCULATE ( 
  COUNTROWS ( 'KasseJournal' ), 
  FILTER ( ALL ( 'KasseJournal' ), 
   'KasseJournal'[Hendelse] = "Bekreftet kasseekspedisjon" 
  ) 
 )
RETURN DIVIDE ( [Totalt antall salg], _TotalSales, 0 )
```